# R's purrr package shortcut dot meaning: .f, .p

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

My question is, I do not quite understand the meaning of the . when writing a function such as implementing a self-designed every() function of purrr predicate functions:

```
every2 <- function(.x, .p, ...) {
  for (i in .x) {
    if (!.p(i, ...)) {
    # If any is FALSE we know not all of then were TRUE
      return(FALSE)
    }
  }# if nothing was FALSE, then it is TRUE
  TRUE
}
every2(1:3, function(x) {x > 1})
#> [1] FALSE
every2(1:3, function(x) {x > 0})
#> [1] TRUE
```

What does the . mean when you type .f?
I have tried it by myself, that even you delete the . in front of the .f and .p, the result of this function still remains correct.
Many thanks for your help! I've been quite confused with these .f and .p.

Comment: I think it's basically just a naming convention, the variable and column names the user is using are unlikely to start with a `.` so the argument names aren't likely to collide with the user's variable names.

Comment: I tried to find the quote by Hadley Wickham but couldn't, but like @Marius said, it's to avoid conflicts of names as many of the functions within the tidyverse are functionals that work in conjunction with other functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marius and MHammer! Your answers really help me grasp the idea of these dots! In Hadley Wickham's book r4ds, he mentioned the shortcuts . , the . is used as a pronoun, and it refers to the current list element just the same way that i referred to the current index in the for loop. So I was a little bit confused whether this shortcut . for current list element has anything to do with the .f, .p in the function arguments.

Comment: No. That is something different. The `.` inside of many tidyverse functions are, as you mentioned, to refer to the current data element being worked on so to say. Don't confuse this with many function arguments that are prefixed with a `.`, like in your example `.x` and `.p`.

Comment: Thank you very much MHammer! You and Marius saved my day!